# SalesForce.com - How to create Book and Video object inheritance from Media?

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I read in Force.com Developer Certification Handbook, in chapter 2 "Creating a Database on Force.com "?  The relationship in show in this picture :

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a bit more to go on, ManhNT.BKIT?

Comment: updated picture, thanks MichaelPetrotta

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking - go to Setup (upper right corner) -> Create -> objects. Find "Video" and "Book" on the list, if they're not there - click the button to create new object(s).

Then you'll be able to add custom fields to them. The field type should be "Lookup" or "Master Detail". For example On Video add new field and select that you want it to point to Media object.

If you're preparing to take the exam I think you've skipped a part of the handbook where they explain it? You can also click "help for this page" once you've arrived at this Setup->Create->Objects menu. And last but not least - you can also do it from Eclipse IDE for example but it's a bit of advanced topic.